# I want to write a Java program to redirect all GET requests from a browser to a given URL using an HTTP 302 response message to the browser

Tags: java, http, webserver

First created the web server:

**Code for the main method**

```
HttpServer server = null;
try {
    server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(9000), 0);
} catch (IOException ex) {

}
server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
server.setExecutor(null);
server.start();
```

in the same class I created Myhandelr class In order to redirect all GETs request to google.com or any website.

```
static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        String response = "This is the response";
        boolean redirect=false;
        if(t.getRequestMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
            t.sendResponseHeaders(302, response.length());
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost:9000")
                .openConnection();
            int status = t.getResponseCode();
            if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                    redirect = true;
            }
            if (redirect) {
                String newUrl ="http://www.google.com";
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
                System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + newUrl);
            }
        }
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());

        os.close();
    }
}
```

I have no idea what i did Wrong, also I'm not sure if this the best way to do it.

Comment: 'I have no idea what i did Wrong,' -> you haven't stated what happens at runtime

Comment: Why does `MyHandler` not just send the 302 instead of opening a new connection to itself? Is this an attempt at network recursion?

Comment: "This is the response" printed on browser with 302 status code, but no redirect happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send back a 302, add a `Location` header with the required URL and the browser does all the work for you, there's no need to implement anything in your code.

Comment: I used this code                     t.sendResponseHeaders(302, response.length());
 to send 320 but I don't know how to add a Location header with the required URL

Comment: `HttpExchange` will have a method that can be used to define custom headers. You add one called **Location** with the value being the URL you want to redirect the user to and that's it.

Comment: Finally i did it, this my code:Headers responseHeaders = t.getResponseHeaders();
 responseHeaders.set("Location", "http://www.google.com");        
        t.sendResponseHeaders(302,0);